# Why is my program not picking up on the attached program?

Tags: python, opencv, video, camera

I'm working the FLIR thermal camera and trying to record its output but for some reason when I run my code I get an 8K file that does not contain anything. Also, nothing displays on my screen. I'm not sure what's missing, but can someone look at my code and let me know if I'm missing something? I'm new to Python so I might have missed something obvious:

```
import cv2
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # find the webcam
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/spidev0.0")

    # video recorder
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I', '4', '2', '0')  # cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc() does not exist
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 8, (60, 80))

    # record video
    while (capture.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if ret:
            resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (60, 80))
            video_writer.write(resized_frame)
            cv2.imshow('Video Stream', frame)

        else:
            break

    capture.release()
    video_writer.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I know that the camera works fine because I tested it with another program so I'm not sure why it's not working with this program.

Comment: if cv2.VideoWriter is a standard file object it needs closing when finished writing with video_writer.close()

Comment: Yes, be sure you close the file, it flushes the output buffers. Otherwise your output may not get written to the file.

Comment: That's what `capture.release()` does.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for the video. Perhaps you can try with [pylepton](https://github.com/groupgets/pylepton)?